# Is there any workaround for a generic argument in a functional interface?

Tags: java, generics, functional-interface

I'm trying to shorten my database access code by creating only one method of each type (update, fetch) in the base - Component class.
To do that, I need to store getters and setters somehow to append them to queries when needed - and to not to use reflection.
So I came with this:

```
class Component{
    protected final HashMap<String, Pair<Getter,Setter>> FIELDS = new HashMap<>();
    public void updateInDB(){
        // create update query, iterating through FIELDS (getters)
    }
}


public class TestComponent extends Component {

    private String color1;

    protected TestComponent(String user_id) {
        super(user_id);
        FIELDS.put("color1", new Pair<>(this::getColor1, this::setColor1));
    }

    public String getColor1() {
        return color1;
    }

    public void setColor1(String color1) {
        this.color1 = color1;
    }
}
```

Getter looks like this:

```
public interface Getter<T> {
    T get();
}
```

Setter:

```
public interface Setter<T> {
    void set(T value);
}
```

And the Pair class:

```
public class Pair<A, B> {

    private A first = null;
    private B second = null;

    public Pair(A first, B second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public A getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(A first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public B getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(B second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

}
```

The error is: **B is not a functional interface**, which means that Setter interface is not a functional interface. Is there any possible workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at your `Pair<Getter,Setter>`.  Because you have not parameterised your setter, it is expecting the interface method to appear as follows:

```
void set (Object value);
```

But that's not what `setColor1` is.  It expects a `String`, not just any old `Object`.

Now in order to get this to compile, you need to add type parameters to your `Setter`:

```
protected final HashMap<String, Pair<Getter<String>,Setter<String>>> FIELDS = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: The issue is not related to your diamond notation, but rather your use of raw types.

Comment: Yep. The other solution is to cast the setter to a concrete type. Thanks!